# Intel Joule Ubuntu Desktop install fails at GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, intel

I've followed the instructions [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-joule#alternative-install:-ubuntu-desktop-16.04-lts) but the install hangs whilst trying to install Grub. I was originally following the instructions [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/106120) with a standard Ubuntu image and that was hanging as well. I thought that when I found the official Tuchuck image for the Joule, it would have this issue corrected.

I have followed the instructions on the Intel thread to copy the kernel and initrd to the EFI partition and then amend the boot configuration in the BIOS to run the kernel directly. This works fine, but is obviously not sustainable when it comes to upgrading kernel versions. It would be nice if GRUB could be installed.

Has anyone managed to get GRUB working with Ubuntu on Intel Joule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I hadn't updated my BIOS in a while...Tuchuck image installed fine now and just going through secondary setup after booting immediately.